# Display files from server to user

Tags: php, dropzone.js

I am building a php web app in which I want to get all the files in a specific folder and display it to the user (each user has their own folder to store their records) I have managed to upload files using Dropzone.js and I can also display the files using Dropzone.js as well but I can't figure out how to let the client download them or open them. Is there any way to use dropzone.js to open the files when clicked if not to download them in the client computer? Or examples on what other libraries to use to display files and open if possible or download them (the files are images .pdf and word files)

Thanks

Comment: Do you use jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

The are several ways you can do this, one simple way is to send back from the server the url of the image you just upload, and add a link to the image.

In the following example I am wrapping the image preview that dropzone creates with a `<a>` tag, that lets you download the image when you click the preview using jquery:

html:

```
<form action="upload.php" class="dropzone" id="my-dropzone"></form>
```

js:

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
    init: function() {
        this.on('success', function(file) {

            var url = file.xhr.response;

            $('.dz-preview.dz-success').last().wrap(function() {
               var link = $('<a/>');
               link.attr('href', $.trim(url));
               link.attr('download', true);
               return link;
            });;

        });
    }
}
```

php:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'uploadsFolder/' . $_FILES['file']['name'])) {
    echo 'uploadsFolder/' . $_FILES['file']['name'];
}
```

Comment: I am getting a downloded file named 'true' with Failed-Forbidden message while using chrome browser while testing your code. And i am trying to download files which have been aready uploaded to a folder someother time and later you can open it in a new page or download the file i dont want that page to upload just only download